# Check if element exists in a jQuery collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have this html:

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test" id="target"></div>
```

Somewhere in my code I call:

```
var $divs = $('.test');
```

Later, I call:

```
var $target =$('#target');
```

Now, I'd like to check if `$target` is in `$divs`

I expected the below to log `true` on the the 3rd iteration but I get `false` 3 times:

```
var $divs = $('.test');
var $target =$('#target');
console.log($target);
$divs.each(function(){
      console.log($(this));
      console.log($(this) == $target);  // expected true on 3rd iteration
});
```

Looking at the console. it's obvious why this returns false.

**What would be the correct way to check if `$divs` contains `$target` ?**

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unzjakt0/9/)

Comment: use `$(this).is($target)`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thank you! I knew I had done this before but could not remember for the life of me how

Comment: @Vohuman As I understand it, because `[div#target.test, context: document, selector: "#target"]` != `[div#target.test, context: div#target.test]`. Even though they refer to the same dom element, the objects themselves are different. but Im all for learning a more specific reason if you have time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition returns `false` as an object is not equal to another object in JavaScript. As an example:

```
$(window) !== $(window)
```

This is because each time the jQuery constructor is called a *new* object is created.

In your case if you get the wrapped object from the collection your condition will return `true` for the target element:

```
$target.get(0) === this;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that. I did not realize that was the case but it totally makes since now that you point it out. I didn't even consider drilling down to the DOM element like that but that also makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 0):

try to check by id,

```
$divs.each(function(){
      console.log($(this));
      console.log($(this).attr("id") == $target.attr("id"));  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change  `console.log($(this) == $target)` into this `console.log($(this).is($target))`.

For comapring two objects in jquery, use `(a.is(b))` i.e. `.is()` function

```
 var $divs = $('.test');
    var $target =$('#target');
    console.log($target);
    $divs.each(function(){
          console.log($(this));
          console.log($(this).is($target)); 
    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Harpreet_devgun/unzjakt0/15/)